# Why do my Photoshop brushstrokes change color when placed on top of each other?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Here's what happens when I layer red, 100% opacity brushstrokes on top of one another on the same layer:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Your blend mode is not set to Normal. Probably either on Difference or Exclusion. Put this back on Normal:

[image]